# How to return immediately when a task throws exception?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have a list of independent methods that I want to execute in parallel and I need all of them to succeed.

My problem is that when any of them throws an error - the WaitAll is waiting for other  tasks to complete. But I want to immediately return to the caller.

It would be also good to cancel other tasks in this case to not waste resources. I tried to call Cancel on CancellationTokenSource from AggregateException catch block but its too late since all tasks complete (or fail) at this point.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>
     {
          Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FirstTask()),
          Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SecondTask()),
          ...
     };
try
{
     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException aEx)
{
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass down a `CancellationToken` and monitor it, you can call `Task.WhenAny` instead of `Task.WaitAll`, which will return once a task finished. You then can monitor them one by one as they finish:

```
try
{
    while (tasks.Count() > 0)
    {
       var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
       if (task.IsCanceled || task.IsFaulted)
       {
          cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
          // Do something with the exception message by accessing
          // task.Exception.
       }

       tasks.Remove(task);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to check `IsFaulted` too for the original exception.

Comment: I check the code and it waits forever when there is an exception. Shouldn't WhenAny be changed to WaitAny?

Comment: `WhenAny` is the awaitable equivalent of `WaitAny` (in a way). What do you mean by *it waits forever*?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov - I mean it does not exit the loop

Comment: Could you please show the code you use? Also, in which context are you running this? Console app?